# Aurelia Validation: Decorator API deprecated?

Tags: validation, decorator, aurelia

I see from early alpha documentation that the versions of Aurelia validation that were based on validatejs supported decorators like @require. Has this functionality gone away in the 1.0 product? I see no mention in the docs, and the decorators don't seem to be available to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Aurelia Validation Plugin underwent a complete rewrite in summer of 2016. It is no longer based on ValidateJS.

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Are you aware of any plans to add this functionality in the future? Decorators are so much more succinct and perfectly suited to the job.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not that is planned. You could submit a feature request through the github issues for that repo. The team members in charge of it could then respond.